# Javascript round to negative value

Tags: javascript

```js
var d26=237500000;
alert(Math.round((d26*0.5)*0.95,-5));
```

This output is **112812500**. But I need output like **112800000**.
Last 5 number will be 0 (Zero).

In excel this is happening. Not in javascript.

Comment: For me, the alert box says `237500000` which matches neither your output nor example. It does however have the trailing 5 `0`s...

Comment: Same here. The output I got was `237500...`

Comment: Same here i got also 23750000

Comment: `const round = (value, decimalPlaces=0) => +decimalPlaces? Math.round(value * ("1e"+decimalPlaces))/("1e"+decimalPlaces): Math.round(value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var d26=237500000;
alert(Math.round(((d26*0.5)*0.95)/100000)*100000);
```

Comment: Almost all the brackets are redundant: `Math.round(d26*0.5*0.95/100000)*100000` is sufficient, and can be reduced to `Math.round(d26*4.75e-6)*1e5`.

Comment: Roger! @RobG i agree and i think to need to Follow  BODMAS Rules so

Comment: Multiplication and division have equal precedence, so are evaluated left to right. Since the brackets don't modify the order, they're redundant. The only pair that are required are to ensure the value is "floored" before being multiplied by 1e5.

Comment: Roger! My Captan Agree @RobG

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is wrong, but I'd suggest solving it this way:

```js
var d26=237500000;
d26 = d26 /100000;
d26 = Math.round((d26*0.5)*0.95);
alert(d26 = d26 *100000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

```
// Closure
(function() {
  /**
   * Decimal adjustment of a number.
   *
   * @param {String}  type  The type of adjustment.
   * @param {Number}  value The number.
   * @param {Integer} exp   The exponent (the 10 logarithm of the adjustment base).
   * @returns {Number} The adjusted value.
   */
  function decimalAdjust(type, value, exp) {
    // If the exp is undefined or zero...
    if (typeof exp === 'undefined' || +exp === 0) {
      return Math[type](value);
    }
    value = +value;
    exp = +exp;
    // If the value is not a number or the exp is not an integer...
    if (isNaN(value) || !(typeof exp === 'number' && exp % 1 === 0)) {
      return NaN;
    }
    // If the value is negative...
    if (value < 0) {
      return -decimalAdjust(type, -value, exp);
    }
    // Shift
    value = value.toString().split('e');
    value = Math[type](+(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] - exp) : -exp)));
    // Shift back
    value = value.toString().split('e');
    return +(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] + exp) : exp));
  }

  // Decimal round
  if (!Math.round10) {
    Math.round10 = function(value, exp) {
      return decimalAdjust('round', value, exp);
    };
  }
  // Decimal floor
  if (!Math.floor10) {
    Math.floor10 = function(value, exp) {
      return decimalAdjust('floor', value, exp);
    };
  }
  // Decimal ceil
  if (!Math.ceil10) {
    Math.ceil10 = function(value, exp) {
      return decimalAdjust('ceil', value, exp);
    };
  }
})();
```

And then you can use

```
Math.round10((d26*0.5)*0.95,5)
```